# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 50), indices imply (3, 50)

Tags: python, pandas

Using `python3` and `pandas`

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 50), indices imply (3, 50)
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 50), indices imply (3, 50)

I am trying to drop all rows from a data frame that contain NaN.

I've tried a few ways and this is the best solution that errors the least.

```
 df1 = df.dropna()
 df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Aware that I can do it in place/

However, often I get the above errors.

Is there a better way to remove all rows with NaN? Anyone know why the error?

Comment: Which errors? Also, it's best to include all relevant information right away, so please [edit] your question.

Comment: No, removing NaNs works just the way you wrote, but to help you further please show us where the error occured. Please provide us with an [mcve].